# Ruby on Rails/Chat-function to my app with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

## My Goal

Setting:Ruby on rails/Ajax/JQuery
Goal: I would like to add chat-function to my app with Ajax.
My Github：https://github.com/Tatsu88-Tokyo/BulkFriends2

## Error

Error: When I post new message, it's not updated by Ajax.
*The page, posted, is updated, however the other page isn't updated.

## Codes

```
:route
  resources :user, only: [:show, :edit, :update]do
    member do
      get 'profile'
      patch 'profile_update'
      get 'logout'
      get 'friends'
      get 'search'
      get :following, :followers
        resources :messages, only: [:index, :create]
        namespace :api do
          resources :messages, only: :index, defaults: { format: 'json' }
        end
    end
  end
```

```
:views/messages/index

=render "home/header_login"
.messages
  .messages__side
    .messages__side__header
      Messages
    .messages__side__contents
      %ul.message-friends
        %li.message-friends-list
          -@friends.each do |friend|
            .message-friend__line
              .line-message-name
                = link_to messages_path(friend),"data-turbolinks": false do
                  =friend.nickname
                  =link_to '詳細', user_path(friend),class:"detail"
  .messages__main
    .messages__main__header
      =@user.nickname
    .messages__main__contents
      .contents
        =render @messages
    .messages__main__footer
      .messages__main__footer__form
        = form_with model: @message,id: "new_message", local:true,"data-turbolinks": false do |f|
          = f.text_field :content, class: 'form__message', placeholder: 'type a message'
          .form__mask
            = f.label :image, class: 'form__mask__image' do
              %i.fas.fa-image.fa-2x
              = f.file_field :image, class: 'hidden'
          = f.submit 'Send', id: "msgbtn", class: 'form__submit'
```

```
:views/messages/_message

.message{data: {message: {id: message.id}}}
  .upper-message
    .upper-message__user-name
      = message.user.nickname
    .upper-message__date
      = message.created_at.strftime("%Y年%m月%d日 %H時%M分")
  .lower-message
    - if message.content.present?
      %p.lower-message__content
        = message.content
    = image_tag message.image.url, class: 'lower-message__image' if message.image.present?
```

```
:controllers/message
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user
  before_action :set_friend

def index
  send_ids = current_user.messages.where(receive_user_id: @user.id).pluck(:id)
  receive_ids = @user.messages.where(receive_user_id: current_user.id).pluck(:id)
  @message=Message.new
  @messages = Message.where(id: send_ids + receive_ids).order(created_at: :asc)
end

def create
  @message = current_user.messages.new(message_params)
  @message.receive_user_id = @user.id
  if @message.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html{ redirect_to messages_path(@user)}
      format.json
    end
  else
    @messages = @user.messages.includes(:user)
    flash.now[:alert] = 'メッセージを入力してください。'
    redirect_to messages_path(@user)
  end
end


private

def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def set_friend
  @friends = current_user.matchers
end

def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:content, :image).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
end

end
```

```
:controllers/api/messages
class Api::MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @text = Message.where(user_id:current_user,receive_user_id:params[:id])
    last_message_id = @text.ids.last
    @content = @text.find(last_message_id)
    user = User.find(@content.user_id)
    @messages = user.messages.where(user_id:current_user,receive_user_id:params[:id]).where("id > ?", last_message_id)
  end
end
```

I checked "last_message_id" by console log, posted page's "last_message_id" is new one,
but other page's "last_message_id" is not new one.

```
:message.js
$(function(){
  let reloadMessages = function(){
    if (location.href.match(/\/user\/\d+\/messages/)){
      let last_message_id = $('.message:last').data('message-id');
      console.log(last_message_id);
    $.ajax({
      url:'api/messages',
      type:'get',
      dataType:'json',
      data: {id: last_message_id}
    })
    .done(function (messages){
      let insertHTML = '';
      messages.forEach(function (message){
      insertHTML = buildHTML(message);
      $('.contents').append(insertHTML);
      })
      $('.messages__main__contents').animate({scrollTop: $('.contents')[0].scrollHeight});
    })
    .fail(function(){
      alert('自動更新,失敗')
    });
    }
  };

setInterval(reloadMessages, 3000);

  function buildHTML(message){
    let image = message.image ? `<img class="lower-message__image" src=${message.image}>` : ``

    let html = `<div class="message" data-message-id = ${message.id}>
                <div class="upper-message">
                <div class="upper-message__user-name">
                ${message.name}
                </div>
                <div class="upper-message__date">
                ${message.created_at}
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="lower-message">
                <p class="lower-message__content">
                ${message.content}
                </p>
                ${image}
                </div>
                </div>`;
      return html
    }
  $('#new_message').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData(this);
    let url = $(this).attr('action');
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type:"POST",
      data: formData,
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false,
      contentType:false
    })
    .done(function(message){
      let html = buildHTML(message)
      $('.contents').append(html);
      $('.messages__main__contents').animate({scrollTop: $('.contents')[0].scrollHeight});
      $('#new_message')[0].reset();
      $('.form__submit').prop('disabled',false);
    })
    .fail(function(){
      alert('error!');
    })
  })
});
```

```
:views/api/index.json.jbuilder
json.array! @messages do |message|
  json.content message.content
  json.name user.nickname
  json.image message.image.url
  json.created_at message.created_at.strftime("%Y年%m月%d日 %H時%M分")
  json.id message.id
end
```

```
:views/messages/create.json.jbuilder
json.name       current_user.nickname
json.content    @message.content
json.image      @message.image.url
json.created_at @message.created_at.strftime("%Y年%m月%d日 %H時%M分")
json.id @message.id
```

Comment: Using Ajax to do this will only update your browser's window.  If you want to update both you will need to use something along the line of websockets.  Actioncable would be a good place to start as most of the tutorials I see are for chat apps and you are using Rails 5. Something like this https://iridakos.com/programming/2019/04/04/creating-chat-application-rails-websockets

Comment: Thank you for your adivise:) I would like to check Actioncable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I couldn't get latest message id in Api/message controller.
Then, I changed my codes to followings and resolved.

```
class Api::MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    text = Message.where(user_id:current_user,receive_user_id:params[:id])
    last_message_id = params[:last_id]
    @messages = text.includes(:user).where("id > ?", last_message_id)
  end
end
```